# layers compatibility between attention layer and CONV1D in keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras-layer, attention-model

I am building a model in bilstm-attention-conv1d fashion (i want to use multiple conv1d with different kernel sizes) I am facing the layers incompatibility issue between the attention layer and conv1d layer. I have tried Reshape function but it's not working, Following is my code:

**my model is as follows**

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype="int32")
embedded_sequences = Embedding(50000, output_dim=output_dim)(sequence_input)

lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(RNN_CELL_SIZE, return_sequences = True), name="bi_lstm_0")(embedded_sequences)

# Getting our LSTM outputs
(lstm, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c) = Bidirectional(LSTM(RNN_CELL_SIZE, return_sequences=True, return_state=True),
                                                                     name="bi_lstm_1")(lstm)

state_h = Concatenate()([forward_h, backward_h])
state_c = Concatenate()([forward_c, backward_c])

context_vector, attention_weights = Attention(10)(lstm, state_h)

x = Reshape((maxlen, output_dim, 1))(context_vector)


kernel_sizes = [1,2,3,4,5]
convs = []
for kernel_size in range(len(kernel_sizes)):
    conv = Conv1D(128, kernel_size, activation='relu')(x)
    convs.append(conv)
    
avg_pool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(convs)
max_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(convs)
conc = concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])
output = Dense(50, activation="sigmoid")(conc)

model = keras.Model(inputs=sequence_input, outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
```

my code gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-8e5c0c75e84a> in <module>()
     13 context_vector, attention_weights = Attention(10)(lstm, state_h)
     14 
---> 15 x = Reshape((maxlen, output_dim, 1))(context_vector)
     16 
     17 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 952                                                 input_list)
    953 
    954     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1092 
   1093         if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    820       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    821     else:
--> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    823 
    824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
    862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
--> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    864 
    865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs)
    555       # Set the static shape for the result since it might lost during array_ops
    556       # reshape, eg, some `None` dim in the result could be inferred.
--> 557       result.set_shape(self.compute_output_shape(inputs.shape))
    558     return result
    559 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
    546       output_shape = [input_shape[0]]
    547       output_shape += self._fix_unknown_dimension(input_shape[1:],
--> 548                                                   self.target_shape)
    549     return tensor_shape.TensorShape(output_shape)
    550 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in _fix_unknown_dimension(self, input_shape, output_shape)
    534       output_shape[unknown] = original // known
    535     elif original != known:
--> 536       raise ValueError(msg)
    537     return output_shape
    538 

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [256], output_shape = [2500, 100, 1]
```

kindly help me

Comment: You are using bidirectional LSTM, so you have 128 dimensions in each direction, in total 256. Therefore, the attention output has also 256 dimensions, but your CNN accepts an input of 128 dimensions.

Comment: should i use filter size 256 to solve it?